# Read file in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying a very basic shiny app and getting error ! 
I have a simple data set txt file 10x10.
I could read it easily in R, by read.table command :

```
tb=read.table("Data.txt",sep="")
```

the out come is :

```
         V1      V2       V3       V4       V5       V6      V7      V8
1  -1.44736 -0.9583 -1.50346  0.12537  0.06332  1.81820  1.2510  0.5793
2  -0.08243  0.6896  0.91643  1.22713  1.30572  0.67108 -0.2496  0.2021
3   1.03049  1.3470  0.01859 -0.33945 -0.77241 -0.27944  0.2572  0.3229
4   0.96038  0.6042  1.26491  0.07691  0.84525 -0.97459  0.4324  0.8489
5   0.95835 -1.8923 -0.43028  0.57660  0.55485 -0.08226  0.4904 -0.2361
6   1.17600 -0.5480 -0.72248 -0.61439 -1.21602  0.70752  0.5765  1.1586
7   0.72957 -1.4862  2.33438 -1.09799  0.60963  0.26388  1.7796  1.3703
8   0.59776  0.9756 -1.47961  0.19636 -0.79520  0.02594  0.1004  0.1278
9   1.10021 -1.0643  0.12381 -0.96318 -0.52618 -0.56597 -0.6296 -0.5527
10  1.03680 -0.6139  0.30787  1.90541 -0.64111  1.28889  1.2670  0.9928
         V9       V10
1  -1.20396  0.225245
2  -1.47926  0.881382
3   0.73340 -0.344852
4  -0.56226 -1.130889
5   0.95693  0.213951
6  -0.06354  1.260926
7   0.45870  0.894200
8   0.82496 -1.014504
9   0.19422  0.008162
10  0.29386 -0.318137
```

But when I try to do the same in shiny :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file","import file"),
  tableOutput("tb")
)

server <- function(input,output){
 output$tb <-renderTable({
      data <- input$file
      if(is.null(data)){return()} 
      read.table(data$path,sep="")
 }) 
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I'm getting the following error after browsing Data :

```
'file' must be a character string or connection
```

What did I missed in my shiny app ?

Comment: Do you want the user to upload the file, or should it be imported when the app starts?

Comment: @Florian User Upload the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace `data$path` with `data$datapath`. Shiny uses `datapath` to access the actually file address when using `fileInput`.

For future reference, I find that an easy way to debug shiny inputs is `assign(..., envir = globalenv())`to save an input to the global environment for inspection outside of the app.

Your example app functions with that single change:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file","import file"),
  tableOutput("tb")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$tb <-renderTable({
    data <- input$file
    # assign('datainput', data, envir = globalenv()) ## writes data to global environment as "datainput" for inspection.
    if(is.null(data)){return()} 
    read.table(data$datapath,sep="")
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```